# Arch linux not being added to grub2

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub2

I'm installing `Arch Linux` alongside an existing `Elementary OS` & `Windows 10` on an `EFI` system.

So I already have `grub2` working and therefore had to be cautious when installing Arch as I didn't want to mess up my existing `EFI` partition etc.

Everything seemed to go well, but `grub-mkconfig` failed to add Arch to the grub boot menu(It only added `Elementary OS`).

So I booted into `Elementary OS` and tried from there , and it does indeed say it's detected `Arch Linux` but then nothing appears in boot menu !

When I run `os-parted` it states `/dev/sda11:;Arch:linux`

So I'm at a loss as to how to get this working.

I've spent hours googling it but to no avail.  Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I worked it out in the end.
I hadn't mounted boot when I installed the system.

Redone it from scratch now and all going fine. 
6 hours of my life I won't get back but loving it all, learning tons as I go along.

Comment: If this is the solution, then you should mark this answer as correct rather than editing the title to include ``[Solved]``.